# Laravel Query data from model using UUID

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

im using library Emadadly\LaravelUuid\Uuids;

Im using laravel v.8

in documentation [here](https://github.com/EmadAdly/laravel-uuid), we can get/query data using 'uuid'. but i got this error.
[image]

My code

```
$periode = Periode::uuid($input['periode_uuid']);
```

My Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Emadadly\LaravelUuid\Uuids;

class Periode extends Model 
{
    use Uuids;

        protected $table = 'periodes';
        public $timestamps = true;
        protected $fillable = array('uuid', 'program', 'tanggal', 'bulan', 'bulan_angka', 'triwulan', 'lainnya', 'tahun', 'aktif', 'soft_delete', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'tahap', 'waktu_usulan_mulai', 'waktu_usulan_berakhir', 'waktu_laporan_mulai', 'waktu_laporan_berakhir', 'semester', 'biaya');
    }
```

Any solution?

Comment: did you set `default_uuid_column` => `id`, in the `config\uuid.php` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, the "uuid" column is missing in the WHERE clause. Try setting the default column manually in the config/uuid.php as the documentation suggests.

```
default_uuid_column="uuid";
```